# How to find the top n minimum values in a two dimensional numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a simple two dimensional numpy matrix and I need to find the n minimum values in the matrix. I have found some functions which are doing that for a numpy array (argpartition), but I am not sure if it would work on a matrix and won't change the matrix itself. Also I found for a list matrix the use of heapmin but it seems complicated and I have a numpy matrix. I prefer that the matrix won't change but I can use np.copy() to ignore the problem. The minimum values can be anywhere. If someone knows how to face the problem it can be really helpful. Thank you.

As requested, I created a short code to emphasize what I need:

```
import numpy as np

def create_nm_matrix(n,m):
    data=np.random.rand(n,m)
    return data
#I need to find the n minimum values the values 
#can repeat themself  
def find_n_minimum_values(mat,n): 
    pass

mat=create_nm_matrix(100,50)
n=3
print("The array of the 3 minimum values in the matrix is:")
print(find_n_minimum_values(mat,n))
```

Comment: In the entire matrix, or *per* row/column?

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help you.

Comment: In the entire matrix, that is why I typed the minimum values can be anywhere.

Comment: Try sorting it by order ascending and then just get the n first elements from the sorted numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten that matrix, use `np.ravel`, and sort it afterwards:

```
>>> v
array([[2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

>>> v1 = v.ravel()   #flattened the array
>>> v1.sort()        # sorted that.

>>> n = 10           # value of n
>>> v1[:n]
array([2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, basically flatten the array, sort and select.

```
np.sort(x.ravel())[0:n]
```